# Python selenium pickle error

Tags: python, selenium, pickle

if i use selenium==2.41.0 and try to pickle data, i've next problem:

```
TypeError: a float is required pickle
```

code to dump/load selenium driver:

```
with open(fn, 'wb') as out:
    pickle.dump(driver, out, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open(fn, 'rb') as inp:
    self.driver = pickle.load(inp)
```

If i user selenium==2.37.2 all is ok